# Get all values from memcached

Tags: memcached

Is there a way in memcached to just get all values? So instead of saying, with this key, retrieve this value, I want to just dump everything currently in memcached?

Comment: Got it, though not sure about performance, probably slow as hell.

      stats items //To get the slab id
      stats cachedump {SLAB-ID} {MAX-NUMBER-OF-KEYS-TO-RETURN}

Comment: That will not get you all data.  That's not a feature of a cache (e.g. you can't do that in your hard drive cache, processor caches, etc...).

Comment: possible duplicate of [get all keys set in memcached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560150/get-all-keys-set-in-memcached)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the new beta version of memcached (1.6). I believe there is support for a new concept called tap streams. These allow you to stream all keys out of memcached as well as other kinds of streams.