# get all keys set in memcached

Tags: get, memcached, key, telnet

How can I get all the keys set in my memcached instance(s)?

I tried googling, but didn't find much except that `PHP` supports a [`getAllKeys` method](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getallkeys.php), which means it is actually possible to do this somehow. How can I get the same within a telnet session?

I have tried out all the retrieval related options mentioned in [memcached cheat sheet](http://www.lzone.de/articles/memcached.htm) and [Memcached telnet command summary](http://blog.elijaa.org/?post/2010/05/21/Memcached-telnet-command-summary), but none of them work and I am at a loss to find the correct way to do this.

Note: I am currently doing this in development, so it can be assumed that there will be no issues due to new keys being set or other such race conditions happening, and the number of keys will also be limited.

Comment: Check my [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378640/memcached-how-to-break-the-limitation-when-retrieving-all-keys). I had the same problem and I found a solution.

Comment: https://github.com/clickalicious/phpmemadmin looks helpful (if I can figure out how to get it to work with Laravel Homestead Vagrant; currently it's showing no keys).

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Found a way, thanks to the [link here](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/) (with the original [google group discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/YyzonP9HUi0))

First, `Telnet` to your server:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Next, list the items to get the slab ids:

```
stats items
STAT items:3:number 1
STAT items:3:age 498
STAT items:22:number 1
STAT items:22:age 498
END
```

The first number after ‘items’ is the slab id. Request a cache dump for each slab id, with a limit for the max number of keys to dump:

```
stats cachedump 3 100
ITEM views.decorators.cache.cache_header..cc7d9 [6 b; 1256056128 s]
END

stats cachedump 22 100
ITEM views.decorators.cache.cache_page..8427e [7736 b; 1256056128 s]
END
```

Comment: Please note that stats cachedump is an undocumented feature and is not supported by the memcached team. It is meant for debugging only and not intended for production use.

Comment: Oh ok. As I said in my question, I am currently in development mode only and needed that for debugging.

Comment: `b` is bytes, `s` is epoch time seconds

Comment: b = bytes, s = time seconds, what is the key ?

Comment: What whacky relevance things are going on at Stack Overflow that _this_ is the bottom answer?  It has the most upvotes, is objectively the best answer, and is the accepted answer...

Comment: @Dan Maybe you are viewing by active answers first, which sorts the answer posts based on when they last had activity. If yes, you can change that by selecting one of active/oldest/votes from just below the question text. Other than that, this answer is at the top in incognito mode.

Comment: Yup, that's the one!  Thanks @mu無.  Is that the default?

Comment: this was not very helpful if I had 40 slabs

Comment: @NikhilTalreja Feel free to post a better answer for benefit of community, this one worked for my use case at the time.

Comment: There is also `lru_crawler metadump all` that will dump all cache keys, not "just" the first 1M.. https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/bb0980fbbafd4eb723f76918e7ca364360315c1b/doc/protocol.txt#L548

Comment: I come back to this answer every month. It's been essential to me getting my job done this season. Big thanks @mu無

Answer (score 82):

#### `memdump`

There is a `memcdump` (sometimes `memdump`) command for that (part of `libmemcached-tools`), e.g.:

```
memcdump --servers=localhost
```

which will return all the keys.

---

#### `memcached-tool`

In the recent version of `memcached` there is also **`memcached-tool`** command, e.g.

```
memcached-tool localhost:11211 dump | less
```

which dumps all keys and values.

See also:

- [What's the simplest way to get a dump of all memcached keys into a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13940404/55075)
- [How do I view the data in memcache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8420776/55075)

Comment: careful with 'memdump' this command is a great way to crash your terminal.

Comment: Careful! The `dump` sub-command for `memcached-tool` seems to clear out the cache :( --might be safer to use `display` or `stats` first.

Comment: In Ubuntu Xenial, the package that contains memdump is called `libmemcached-tools`, and the tool's binary is called memcdump instead.

Comment: For those looking for `memcached-tool` it's somewhat hidden in a directory, which may not be in a standard `PATH` - at least on Ubuntu Xenial - here: `/usr/share/memcached/scripts/`

Comment: `alias memctool=/usr/share/memcached/scripts/memcached-tool` if you're lazy.

Answer (score 22):

Base on [@mu 無](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860929/mu-%E7%84%A1) answer here. I've written a cache dump script.

The script dumps all the content of a memcached server. It's tested with Ubuntu 12.04 and a localhost memcached, so your milage may vary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'stats items'  \
| nc localhost 11211  \
| grep -oe ':[0-9]*:'  \
| grep -oe '[0-9]*'  \
| sort  \
| uniq  \
| xargs -L1 -I{} bash -c 'echo "stats cachedump {} 1000" | nc localhost 11211'
```

What it does, it goes through all the cache slabs and print 1000 entries of each.

Please be aware of certain limits of this script i.e. it may not scale for a 5GB cache server for example. But it's useful for debugging purposes on a local machine.

Comment: On Debian 8 with `memcached 1.4.21-1.1+deb8u1` I had to explicitly send a quit command to memcached. I modified your command to this and works properly now: `echo -e "stats items\nquit"  | nc localhost 11211 | grep -oe ':[0-9]*:'  |  grep -oe '[0-9]*' | sort | uniq | xargs -L1 -I{} bash -c 'echo -e "stats cachedump {} 1000\nquit" | nc localhost 11211'` Thanks for sharing this! Quite useful for debugging :)

Comment: for some reason grep -oe '[0-9]*' doesn't work in iTerm2 on mac, had to replace with grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,99}'

Comment: This is nifty, but it misses some keys, any idea why ?

Comment: IMO this is automated version of the currently most upvoted option. i have not tried it myself yet. but i give upvote for trying to automate.

Answer (score 21):

If you have PHP & PHP-memcached installed, you can run

```
$ php -r '$c = new Memcached(); $c->addServer("localhost", 11211); var_dump( $c->getAllKeys() );'
```

Comment: You need to do this  after  addServer : `$c->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, false);`

For newer versions of Memcached

Comment: Still the answer is bool(false) :-(

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen - that's due to a bug in memcached - it's fixed in newest versions.  https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/203

Comment: @billynoah Thx, I really see results now and memcached is starting to get useful :-)

Answer (score 17):

### Bash

To get list of keys in Bash, follow the these steps.

First, define the following wrapper function to make it simple to use (copy and paste into shell):

```
function memcmd() {
  exec {memcache}<>/dev/tcp/localhost/11211
  printf "%s\n%s\n" "$*" quit >&${memcache}
  cat <&${memcache}
}
```

---

#### Memcached 1.4.31 and above

You can use `lru_crawler metadump all` command to dump (most of) the metadata for (all of) the items in the cache.

> As opposed to `cachedump`, it does not cause severe performance problems and has no limits on the amount of keys that can be dumped.

Example command by using the previously defined function:

```
memcmd lru_crawler metadump all
```

See: [ReleaseNotes1431](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes1431).

---

#### Memcached 1.4.30 and below

Get list of slabs by using [items statistics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/memcached/memcached_stats_items.htm) command, e.g.:

```
memcmd stats items
```

For each slub class, you can get list of items by specifying slub id along with limit number (`0` - unlimited):

```
memcmd stats cachedump 1 0
memcmd stats cachedump 2 0
memcmd stats cachedump 3 0
memcmd stats cachedump 4 0
...
```

<sup>Note: You need to do this for each memcached server.</sup>

To list all the keys from all stubs, here is the one-liner (per one server):

```
for id in $(memcmd stats items | grep -o ":[0-9]\+:" | tr -d : | sort -nu); do
    memcmd stats cachedump $id 0
done
```

<sup>Note: The above command could cause severe performance problems while accessing the items, so it's not advised to run on live.</sup>

---

Notes:

> `stats cachedump` only dumps the `HOT_LRU` (IIRC?), which is managed by a background thread as activity happens. This means under a new enough version which the 2Q algo enabled, you'll get snapshot views of what's in just one of the LRU's.
>
> If you want to view everything, `lru_crawler metadump 1` (or `lru_crawler metadump all`) is the new mostly-officially-supported method that will asynchronously dump as many keys as you want. you'll get them out of order but it hits all LRU's, and unless you're deleting/replacing items multiple runs should yield the same results.

Source: [GH-405](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/405#issuecomment-402807539).

---

Related:

- [List all objects in memcached](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/YyzonP9HUi0)
- [Writing a Redis client in pure bash](http://milhouseonsoftware.com/2015/07/27/writing-a-redis-client-in-pure-bash-part-1/) (it's Redis, but very similar approach)
- Check other available commands at https://memcached.org/wiki
- Check out the [`protocol.txt`](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) docs file.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use python-memcached-stats package, https://github.com/abstatic/python-memcached-stats

The keys() method should get you going.

Example -

```
from memcached_stats import MemcachedStats
mem = MemcachedStats()

mem.keys()
['key-1',
 'key-2',
 'key-3',
 ... ]
```

Comment: You can even do it from the command line with `python -m memcached_stats <ip> <port>`

Comment: Python2 only, at the moment.

Comment: Will there be any limit in terms of the number of keys returned or size?

Answer (score 1):

I was using Java's spyMemcached, and used this code. It is based on [Anshul Goyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860929/anshul-goyal)

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("initMemcachedClient")
private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;

public List<String> getCachedKeys(){
    Set<Integer> slabIds = new HashSet<>();
    Map<SocketAddress, Map<String, String>> stats;
    List<String> keyNames = new ArrayList<>();

    // Gets all the slab IDs
    stats = memcachedClient.getStats("items");
    stats.forEach((socketAddress, value) -> {
        System.out.println("Socket address: "+socketAddress.toString());
        value.forEach((propertyName, propertyValue) -> {
            slabIds.add(Integer.parseInt(propertyName.split(":")[1]));
        });
    });

    // Gets all keys in each slab ID and adds in List keyNames
    slabIds.forEach(slabId -> {
        Map<SocketAddress, Map<String, String>> keyStats = memcachedClient.getStats("cachedump "+slabId+" 0");
        keyStats.forEach((socketAddress, value) -> {
            value.forEach((propertyName, propertyValue) -> {
                keyNames.add(propertyName);
            });
        });
    });

    System.out.println("number of keys: "+keyNames.size());
    return keyNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit - first I posted here yet another solution based on slab list + stats cachedump, but then I've learnt a hard lesson, that the latter doesn't return all of the keys.

See also [memcached issue #405](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/405).

Luckily, there is [better solution](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes1431#overview): `lru_crawler metadump all`.

The only funny thing is that `lru_crawler` returns url-encoded keys. I didn't like that, so my shortest script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=localhost
port=11211

run_memc() {
    nc -q0 $host $port
}

echo 'lru_crawler metadump all' | run_memc | grep -v ^END \
    | ruby -rcgi -ne 'puts CGI.unescape $_' | sort
```

I used Ruby's `unescape` because that was the shortest: Perl doesn't seem to have unescape/urldecode out of the box, Python import + loop would be definitely not a oneliner, and I always got some Ruby installed. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: To run above script on macOs I had to use `nc $host $port` (removed `-q0`)

Answer (score 0):

**Java Solution:**

Thanks! @Satvik Nema
Your solution helped me to find the approach, but it doesn't work for memcached `2.4.6` version. (`implementation 'com.googlecode.xmemcached:xmemcached:2.4.6'`)
Not sure when did new method `getStatsByItem` included.
I figured out required changes using documentation and below code worked for me.

```
// Gets all the slab IDs
            Set<Integer> slabIds = new HashSet<>();
            Map<InetSocketAddress, Map<String, String>> itemsMap = null;
            try {
                itemsMap = this.memcachedClient.getStatsByItem("items");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed while pulling 'items'. ERROR", e);
            }
    
            if (Objects.nonNull(itemsMap)) {
                itemsMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    log.info("itemsMap {} : {}", key, value);
                    value.forEach((k, v) -> {
                        slabIds.add(Integer.parseInt(k.split(":")[1]));
                    });
                });
            }
    
            // Gets all keys in each slab ID and adds in List keyNames
            slabIds.forEach(slabId -> {
                Map<InetSocketAddress, Map<String, String>> keyStats = null;
                try {
                    keyStats = this.memcachedClient.getStatsByItem("cachedump " + slabId + " 0");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Failed while pulling 'cachedump' for slabId: {}. ERROR", slabId, e);
                }
                if (Objects.nonNull(keyStats)) {
                    keyStats.forEach((socketAddress, value) -> {
                        value.forEach((propertyName, propertyValue) -> {
                            //keyNames.add(propertyName);
                            log.info("keyName: {} Value: {}", propertyName, propertyValue);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```