# Laravel 5.1 cache tags path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using tags cache to cache data. I need to know, where this cached data actually stored ?

```
$response = Cache::tags(Locationsinv::table())->remember($cacheKey, $this->ttlCache, function() {
            return Locationsinv::select([
                    'id', 'location', 'status'
                ])->orderBy('id')->get();
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the `Cache` is stored depends on your configuration if you check out the Laravel docs for [`Cache`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache) it states

> The cache configuration is located at config/cache.php. In this file
>   you may specify which cache driver you would like used by default
>   throughout your application. Laravel supports popular caching backends
>   like Memcached and Redis out of the box.
>
> By default, Laravel is configured to use the file cache driver, which
>   stores the serialized, cached objects in the filesystem.

so most likely it will be stored within your projects storage directory ( with the default directory being `storage/framework/cache/`). Unless you've changed the configuration.

Comment: Thanks.'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'), Used file cache driver in my code. But not found any cache files at (storage/framework/cache/). Please help

Comment: Not overridden in your `.env` file?

Comment: Thanks @Mark  .Oh sorry! its memcache driver. CACHE_DRIVER=memcached in .env file.

Comment: Cool glad that solved your problem. If  you want to check out the contents of your memcache you might want to look at the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560150/get-all-keys-set-in-memcached